# How to open/import .rds file without R?

Tags: r

I have an .rds (R Data Storage) file that I need to open and access on my ChromeOS device. I have no programming experience and cannot install R directly.

Is there a way for me to open and view the contents of an .rds file on ChromeOS without programming knowledge or installing additional software?

I have searched online for ways to open the file but couldn't find a straightforward solution that doesn't require programming knowledge or installing R.

I was expecting to find a way to open the .rds file directly on my ChromeOS device, without the need for programming experience.

Any assistance or guidance in achieving this goal would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could use [RStudio Cloud](https://posit.cloud/). If you upload the .rds file as `"my_data.rds"`, run `dat <- readRDS("my_data.rds")` to read it into an object called `dat`. You can then enter `dat` to print it to the console, or click on `dat` in the environment panel on the upper right to use the RStudio viewer. Exporting in another format will depend on what exactly is in the `.rds`; if it’s just a dataframe, you can do `write.csv(dat, "my_data.csv")`, which you should then be able to open in say Google Sheets.

Comment: @zephryl how do I upload the file?

Comment: There should be an option in the lower right panel.

Comment: You could also try using the web assembly version of R which works in your browser: https://webr.r-wasm.org/latest/.
To upload a file click on the "Files" tab in the right pane, expand the "home" folder, then the "web_user" folder and upload your RDS file.
The rest of the commands would then be the same as what @zephryl specified in their comment.